# Is there a way to see BLE communication from another App?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am trying to synch a light source with a low-energy Bluetooth device (Imagine a RGB flashlight Controller by BLE from a closed-source App) with another light and can't find anything in how to Snoop another App's or the whole phones Bluetooth Data. Rooting the physical device is No Problem.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Yes. Search the web for "Android hci log".

Comment: From what I've read this enables me to log HCI into a file, however I want to have that data accessible in an Android Application so I can use it to decide if and how to run logic when a specific device got a specific color/brightness change.

Comment: If you simply execute connectGatt you can hook up to an already established connection. You can then register for notifications that are meant to only be sent to the other app. You can not access gatt write or read requests however using this method. It's still very unclear from your post exactly what you are trying to do.